# Changing title within loop

Tags: gnuplot

I am using gnuplot 5.0, and I have a data set I would like to plot using

```
key1 = 'Some title with multiple words'
key2 = 'Some other descriptive title '
key3 = '...and a third title'
plot for[i=1:3] datafile index i-1 using 1:2 with lines title eval('key'.i)
```

This is not working, but I would like to have a different string with multiple words for each curve. Using `words()` and `word()` will not work. So, how can I change the title in a plot-for command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gnuplot 5.0 introduces some limited support for using quoted strings with `word` and `words`:

```
keys = '"Some title with multiple words" '.\
       '"Some other descriptive title" '.\
       '"...and a third title"'
plot for[i=1:3] i*x with lines title word(keys, i)
```

[image]